# How to load a View model when Window or view is loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created a simple application in C# with a view model and usually you have to declare the view model in he datacontext of the window or usercontrol for it to load. Problem is it loads whenever visual studio has the application opened.

I want it to load when the application is running and window is loaded.

```
<Window x:Class="GraphApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:GraphApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <!-- Insert Model view Here. I want it to load when the window is running, not when I have it opened in visual studio.-->

    </Window.DataContext>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why is the loading of the ViewModel in the Designer a problem for you?

Comment: Does the view model not load when you open the window (run the app)? I'm not sure what you mean by 'loading in visual studio'...

Comment: you mean loaded in the visual studio forms designer?

Comment: Yes I do mean loaded from the forms designer. I get a popup every time the window is loaded in my environment, it's meant to load in the customer's environment. I just wanted a way to prevent that.

Comment: the visual studio forms designer always runs the constructor for the form/control, just move your code to the load event (see answers below), or make it manual based on a control interaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, when we want something to happen after an element has loaded, we handle the [`FrameworkElement.Loaded` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Another way to achieve this would be to set some `DataTemplate`s and have a property of either the type of your view model, or of a common base view model class:

```
public BaseViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged here
```

Then in `App.xaml Resources`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:FirstViewModel}">
    <Views:FirstTrackView />
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:LastViewModel}">
    <Views:LastTrackView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you can implicitly set the `DataContext` whenever you like in this way and the corresponding view will automatically be displayed:

```
ViewModel = new SomeViewModel();
```

Comment: That might be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the `Window.Loaded` event and:

```
void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if the event is not raised by the visual studio designer
    if(DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
      return;

    //Set the data context:
    this.DataContext = //Your viewmodel here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old now, but you can to this by first adding a namespace where your view model is located.

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyWpfForm.ViewModel"
```

Then add this directly under your closing Window Element

```
<Control.DataContext>
   <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
</Control.DataContext>
```

where "MainWindowViewModel" is your view model's constructor.